# Open source software/library/tool/patch/... for converting audio to MIDI suggestions?

Tags: audio, midi, software, library, puredata

Having found 2 open source tools that can convert any audio file to midi, I'm still interested if there are others (for comparison).

I've tried [WaoN](https://github.com/kichiki/WaoN) and [Audio_to_midi_melodia](https://github.com/justinsalamon/audio_to_midi_melodia).

But not all samples produce desirable output.

WaoN seems to work better overall, and tweaking the parameters (as well as using higher sampling rates as input) aids in getting more accurate results.

Any tips for other OSS tools or libraries that achieve something similar are greatly appreciated.

Comment: MIDI is not a type of audio file. It's not like converting .wav to .mp3 See this on [How stuff works](https://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/midi1.htm) Maybe I don't understand what you're asking but it seems like you want to extract drum samples and play them back with a MIDI device.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this indeed. WaoN is not trivial and understanding more about it is interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764521/waon-wav-to-midi-conversion 
I am not interested in MIDI devices, just having MIDI files that capture the main gist of a song or sample (rhythm/melody wise).

Comment: [Audacity](https://audacityteam.org) is opensource and it does have one such conversion function as far as I remember,
Have you ever tried it? If so please let me know your feedback..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about free and open source but ableton does this with a right click on an audio file > convert to midi

Maybe you could extract this midi out of the trial version or something like that?

Comment: Thanks, I assume that indeed proprietary software has some solutions (like Melodyne https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1Zkznqs-f8) but I am actually only interested in open source software, and not because its free so working with trial versions is not that relevant. Thanks regardless!

Answer (score 1):

it seems that [rackarrack](http://rakarrack.sourceforge.net/) has an audio to midi converter inside. The plugin is for guitar sounds but you can probably have a look at the code and see how this is made.

There's also [aubio](https://aubio.org) with a command line dedicated to audio to midi conversion [aubionotes](https://aubio.org/aubionotes.html) same thing here, you can probably have a look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852102/software-to-convert-audio-to-midi/65444119#65444119

which describes using Sonic Analyser or Tony.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to see this,which converting piano audio to MIDI https://github.com/bytedance/GiantMIDI-Piano.it may need a little bit modification of the program.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to see this,which converting piano audio to MIDI
the site is:https://github.com/bytedance/GiantMIDI-Piano
it may need a little bit modification of the program to use.